# MongoDB gridFS displaying all images

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I'm currently using two files, one gets the content and the second displays it (or tries too)

What I need to do is iterate through the images stored in gridFS to display them all, I can get the filenames to iterate, and the filename is within the paramiter of the find, but it doesn't work, I just get a broken image, here is the code:

display.php

```
 <?php
   // open connection to MongoDB server
  $conn = new Mongo;

  // access database
  $db = $conn->database;

  // get GridFS files collection
  $grid = $db->getGridFS();

  $cursor = $grid->find(); 

    foreach ($cursor as $obj) {                   // iterate through the results
        $filename = $obj->getFilename().'<br/>';
    echo "<img src='newupload.php?filename=".$filename."'>";
    echo $filename;
    }


?>
```

and here is the one that goes into gridFS

```
<?php
  $filename = $_GET['filename'];
try {
  // open connection to MongoDB server
  $conn = new Mongo;

  // access database
  $db = $conn->database;

  // get GridFS files collection
  $grid = $db->getGridFS();

  // retrieve file from collection
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  $file = $grid->find(array('filename' => $filename ));

  // send headers and file data

  echo $file->getBytes();
  exit;  

  // disconnect from server
  $conn->close();
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
  die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
} catch (MongoException $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `find()` method of the `MongoGridFS` object returns a cursor, not a `MongoGridFSFile` object; the cursor has no `getBytes()` method. The actual output you're receiving is probably one of the `die(...)` messages in your catch clauses, which the browser cannot display as an image.

Instead of `find(array('filename' => $filename))`, you should probably use `findOne(array('filename' => $filename))`.

Note that if there are several files with the same file name, you may need to drop to a lower level to ensure that you find the one you want (which one you want depends on your needs; perhaps it is the first, perhaps it is the most recent, or perhaps it is based on some other criteria). In this situation, you can query the GridFS collection manually (it is named "fs.files"), find the file you wish to return, and pass its `_id` to the `get()` method of `MongoGridFS`.